# Getting targetCell error on Google Form Submit Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to Create Unique Ticket no. after each Form submission but getting following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")
```

Here is the Complete Script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Generates a unique ticket number for every form submission.
  function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var targetCell = e.range.offset(0, e.range.getNumColumns(), 1, 1);

    // Get a public lock on this script, because we're about to modify a shared resource.
    var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
    // Wait for up to 30 seconds for other processes to finish.
    lock.waitLock(30000);

    var ticketNumber = Number(ScriptProperties.getProperty('lastTicketNumber')) + 1;
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('lastTicketNumber', ticketNumber);

    // Release the lock so that other processes can continue.
    lock.releaseLock();

    targetCell.setValue(ticketNumber);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving that error because the event object, `e`, isn't defined when you've called `onFormSubmit(e)`. This is typical when you are debugging, and have invoked a parameterized function from the editor/debugger.

For your testing, simulate the event using the technique from [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas/16089067#16089067)

(Did you intend to wrap `onFormSubmit(e)` inside `myFunction()`? I would think not.)